# Значение слова

Tags: значение-слов

если скажут, чтобы я написал два слова( стол и стул) так,чтобы слово( стул) стояло перед словом (стол) ,какое слово написать первым?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом случае удобнее написать сперва слово "стул", а затем "стол". Можно  сделать отступление написать *стол*, после чего в отступ вписать *стул*. Можно взять по ручке в каждую руку и одновременно левой выводить *стул*,а правой *стол*. Как душа пожелает писать можно. Указаний на последовательность написания в тексте нет. (капитан Очевидность)

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос непонятен. Если вам "скажут написать так **"чтобы слово( стул) стояло перед словом (стол)"**, то так и пишите. ))))

Comment: А без ответов разве было неясно? То ли розыгрыш, то ли ...

Comment: Уважаемый,Behemothus,Ваш ответ мне очень понравился,два раза ответ не принимается ,смог только проголосовать,большое спасибо!!!